# Cannot resolve symbol "RecycleView"

Tags: java, android

The problem basically is that when trying to RecyclerView in the class I get error "Can not resolve symbol" RecycleView "

**This is my gradle code**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.+'
```

**This is my class**

```
package com.example.admin.economizate;
     public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView{
}
```

Comment: Import the class then.

Answer (score 2):

A `ViewHolder` should not extend a `RecyclerView`, but you need an import statement regardless

You would want

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;

public class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
```

---

Note: You already have `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'`, so remove the `recyclerview-v7:28.0.+'` line

Comment: Also, `appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'` looks duplicate and unnecessary.

Comment: when i try this, the error is "cannot resolve simbol 'widget' "

Comment: Sounds like something else is wrong with gradle that is not allowing your code to compile. For example, open a terminal outside of Android Studio for your project and run `./gradlew compile`